# Configurar headers no Axios?

Tags: javascript, header, axios, content-type

Estou utilizando o Axios para fazer as requisições entre cliente e servidor, porém estou com problemas nos `headers`. Quando faço as requisições pelo Postman retorna exatamente o que eu quero(que no caso é um PDF), mas quando eu faço a requisição através do meu cliente ele retorna um PDF que não é o que eu quero, na verdade nem sei de onde está vindo aquele PDF.

Usei o Beyond Compare e pude ver as diferenças nos `headers`, e vou mostrar abaixo:

headers do Postman:

`headers:
   { host: 'localhost:9000',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'postman-token': '75a0b30b-03ae-574f-fa40-d36c30e14e76',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     encoding: 'UTF-8',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',
     'content-type': 'application/pdf',
     accept: '*/*',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
     'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' },
  rawHeaders:
   [ 'Host',
     'localhost:9000',
     'Connection',
     'keep-alive',
     'Postman-Token',
     '75a0b30b-03ae-574f-fa40-d36c30e14e76',
     'Cache-Control',
     'no-cache',
     'Encoding',
     'UTF-8',
     'User-Agent',
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',
     'Content-Type',
     'application/pdf',
     'Accept',
     '*/*',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'gzip, deflate, br',
     'Accept-Language',
     'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' ]`

Headers do cliente:

`headers:
   { cookie: 'Phpstorm-ede8a916=ef6f3db8-812c-47ae-84e1-fcd03915f7f4',
     'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
     referer: 'http://localhost:8080/',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',
     accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     pragma: 'no-cache',
     connection: 'close',
     host: 'localhost:9000' },
  rawHeaders:
   [ 'cookie',
     'Phpstorm-ede8a916=ef6f3db8-812c-47ae-84e1-fcd03915f7f4',
     'accept-language',
     'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
     'accept-encoding',
     'gzip, deflate, br',
     'referer',
     'http://localhost:8080/',
     'user-agent',
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',
     'accept',
     'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     'cache-control',
     'no-cache',
     'pragma',
     'no-cache',
     'connection',
     'close',
     'host',
     'localhost:9000' ]`

```
axios.get('/server/baixarpdf', { headers: {'content-type': 'application/pdf'}})
      .then(function(response) {
        let blob = new Blob([response.data], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
        })
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        window.open(url);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
```

As diferenças estão nos 'content-type' e no 'accept', e quero saber como mudar essas configurações, pois não consegui achar o que preciso na documentação do Axios(ou não entendi).

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei outra solução, segue o código:

```
axios.get('/server/arquiv', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
      .then(function(response) {

        let file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.open(fileURL);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
```